# Extract Outlook Email Information to Excel from Specific Dates vba

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have several emails sent to me on a daily basis or every 15 days, I need to keep track that they are being delivered on time.

I have created rules on Outlook for them to be stored on different folders and subfolders.

What I'd like to do is have an Excel Sheet that compares Objective Date/Time Vs Actual Date/Time delivery. For this I need to extract the Sent Time and Date from Outlook and Export it to Excel. I'm not sure if to do it based on Folder/Subfolder name or Pieces of Subject, as it is done for my rules.

I have read the answer of similar questions but have not being able to adjust it to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Search Folder that indexes the specific folders containing these emails.  Then loop through Folder.Items for that Search Folder to extract the properties you need from each MailItem in the Items collection.